# hg push casues error called abort: stream: not a Mercurial bundle

Tags: mercurial

It does not cause any problem until I add or commit, but when I push my changes to the repo, it gives me error that looks like this

```sh
(idea_spread_hospital)istanbul:Idea-Propagation-Model$ hg push --debug --traceback
pushing to /home/projects/Social/Idea-Propagation-Model
query 1; heads
searching for changes
all remote heads known locally
listing keys for "bookmarks"
3 changesets found
list of changesets:
e08e7105bdb8c9508be2f3b375e6d6b7b096dabe
c69097225b3cfeedf0bcc0c1cc211004bb9a255c
d7eddf2b05876a2216cfbf0552e2870c803ebb6b
bundling: 1/3 changesets (33.33%)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 138, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 819, in _dispatch
    cmdpats, cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 599, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 910, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 881, in checkargs
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 816, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 518, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 4717, in push
    newbranch=opts.get('new_branch'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 1725, in push
    return exchange.push(self, remote, force, revs, newbranch)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/exchange.py", line 140, in push
    _pushchangeset(pushop)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/exchange.py", line 289, in _pushchangeset
    'push')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 127, in unbundle
    cg = exchange.readbundle(self.ui, cg, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/exchange.py", line 30, in readbundle
    raise util.Abort(_('%s: not a Mercurial bundle') % fname)
Abort: stream: not a Mercurial bundle
: stream: not a Mercurial bundle
```

Could someone explain what does `abort: stream: not a Mercurial bundle error` means ?

Comment: Is one of the changesets a HUGE changeset which causes problems in transmission? https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StaticBundlePlan I suggest to try asking in #mercurial on freenode during American day time.

Comment: @planetmaker Yes, I have a folder that is very big, but I put that entire folder in .hgignore

Comment: The question is whether you have big changesets (i.e. big files which are tracked) which could have the transmission fail (i.e. due to too small packages configured in server to receive or send stuff)? Adding files and then adding them to .hgignore won't untrack them.